# Group distinct values in same column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Value List containing the following values:

```
Segmentation | CurrentValue | PreviousValue

 CITY A            2            0
 CITY B            5            0
 CITY C            0            2
 CITY A            0            3
 CITY C            5            0
```

I have tried this:

```
var groupedValues= dadosZoom.Select(d => new { d.Segmentation, d.PreviousValue, d.CurrentValue }).
    GroupBy(x => x.Segmentation, (key) => new
         {
            key.Segmentation,
            key.PreviousValue,
            key.CurrentValue
         }).ToList();
```

i Expect an output like this:

```
Segmentation | CurrentValue | PreviousValue

 CITY A            2            3
 CITY B            5            0
 CITY C            5            2
```

But the actual return is a Dictonary:`System.Linq.Lookup<string,<>f__AnonymousType1<string, double, double>>.Grouping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the max `PreviousValue` and `CurrentValue` for each `Segmentation`.  So you need to do an aggregation like this.

```
var groupedValues= dadosZoom.GroupBy(x => x.Segmentation)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Segmentation = grp.Key,
        PreviousValue = grp.Max(x => x.PreviousValue),
        CurrentValue = grp.Max(x => x.CurrentValue)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or if you need the sum just use `Sum` instead of `Max`.